# Parity Ethereum - Public network

Tags: private-blockchain

Want to create my own public network with pre-funded account, can any one point out the optimise, secure configuration for spanning node for Test and  Main net ?

To be more specific for Test Net I need 
- Genesis.json
- Toml file with all  necessary configuration

and for main net
- Genesis.json
- Toml file with all  necessary configuration

Comment: There are many tutorials that explain how to create a genesis file. Any of them should work fine. Unless you have a specific issue your question is just too broad.

Comment: I got many tutorials but none of them are telling actual configuration for which is required for the main net? it would be great if you can help me in setting up the main net Genesis file which yields high hight TPS and one account prefunded.

Comment: Any genesis should be fine for a blockchain. You mention TPS but it has no meaning without more details and intended use. Some parameters like gas are dynamic and can be adjusted afterward.

Comment: The intended use can be recording transactions from IOT devices, just an example, which need high TPS

Comment: Title with "public network" and tag with "private-blockchain" is confusing.